# Invoke JNI_OnLoad from Delphi

Tags: android, c++, delphi, android-ndk

i've a native c++ library that i wantto use in my delphi android project; 
Here's the important part that i want to invoke it from Delphi code part:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>

#define  LOG_TAG    "EmbJniTest"
#define  LOGI(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)


JavaVM* gJavaVM = NULL;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* aVm, void* aReserved)
{
 // cache java VM
 gJavaVM = aVm;
 JNIEnv* env;// latter on it'll be used as global var
 LOGI("JVM INIT");
 if (aVm->GetEnv(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&env), JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK)
 {
  LOGI("Failed to get the environment");
  return -1;
 }
 return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}
```

and here's my delphi code part to load mylibrary :

```
LIBNAME = 'libtest.so';


function try_load_dll:integer;
var libPath:system.string;
begin
  _status:= 0 ;
  libPath:=TPath.Combine(tpath.GetLibraryPath,libname);
  _status := LoadLibrary(PChar(libPath));
  result:=_Status;
  if( _status= 0 )then exit;
end;
```

The problem is that the

```
JNI_OnLoad
```

Is never invoked ; i can't see any log about it in the logcat .

And i've read that The invocation of JNI_OnLoad is done by System.loadLibrary().  If 
you're not using that to load the library, JNI_OnLoad won't happen.

from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/android-ndk/cKZRjSMUemw)
So please is there anyway i can invoke it from my delphi code .

Thank you

Comment: You could call it, but what are you going to pass in for `JavaVM*` ?

Comment: @RichardCritten , latter on i'll save  JNIEnv* env as global variable to use it in some procedures and functions within my native lib

Comment: Just wondering why JNI_OnLoad is not being invoked , i can’t see any log about

Comment: @pskink , i’ve no java code just my native Lib and Delphi as a consumer App only

Comment: @RemyLebeau , thank you so there's no other option / solution than calling `JNI_OnLoad` function within my delphi code ?

Comment: You could perhaps try actually using System.loadLibrary, however you would need to use an import for the System class for at least that method, e.g: https://pastebin.com/giM3fEda

Comment: if i call the `JNI_OnLoad() ` in my delphi code as follows : 
`function JNI_OnLoad(VM: PJavaVM; reserved: pointer): JInt; cdecl;
begin
  // should i intialize my VM pointer here or what ?
end;`

Comment: @bodam: See the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Just wondering why `JNI_OnLoad` is not being invoked

`JNI_OnLoad()` is normally called by the Java JVM if it is the one loading your native library (ie, when Java code calls [`System.loadLibrary()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary(java.lang.String))).

Since that is not the case in your example, that is why your `JNI_OnLoad()` is not being called. You are directly loading the library yourself, so you will have to call `JNI_OnLoad()` yourself.

Embarcadero declares a `TJNI_OnLoad` function pointer type in the `Embarcadero.Jni` unit. Use `GetProcAddress()` to get a pointer to the library's exported `JNI_OnLoad()` function, and assign that pointer to a `TJNI_OnLoad` variable. Then you can call `JNI_OnLoad()` like any other function.

> latter on i'll save `JNIEnv* env` as global variable to use it in some procedures and functions within my native lib

`JNI_OnLoad()` takes a `JavaVM*` pointer as input. Whoever calls `JNI_OnLoad()` must pass in a pointer to a valid `JavaVM` object.

The Java JVM would normally handle that for you.  But, since you are loading the library yourself, and thus have to call `JNI_OnLoad()` yourself, you have to provide a `JavaVM` object from your Delphi code.  Rather than call `JNI_CreateJavaVM()` yourself, you *should* be able to use the same `JavaVM` object that Delphi's RTL uses internally - the `JavaMachine` pointer in the RTL's `System` unit (just typecast it to `PJavaVM`, which is also declared in the `Embarcadero.Jni` unit).

Try this:

```
uses
   ..., Embarcadero.Jni

const
  LIBNAME = 'libtest.so';

function try_load_dll: THandle;
var
  libPath: string;
  OnLoadFunc: TJNI_OnLoad;
  hlib: THandle;
begin
  Result := 0;
  libPath := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetLibraryPath, libname);
  hlib := LoadLibrary(PChar(libPath));
  if hlib = 0 then Exit;
  @OnLoadFunc := GetProcAddress(hlib, 'JNI_OnLoad');
  if not Assigned(OnLoadFunc) then
  begin
    FreeLibrary(hlib);
    Exit;
  end;
  OnLoadFunc(PJavaVM(System.JavaMachine), nil);
  Result := hlib;
end;
```